# Jsforce: Create record with Picklist value - INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am using `jsforce` to create a new object in Salesforce. I am going to build an integration but I am just doing some quick tests before I build the rest of it. Here is my test code.

```
const jsforce = require('jsforce');
const moment = require('moment');
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  loginUrl: 'https://***.salesforce.com',
});

const create = {
  IsoCode: 'AED',
  ConversionRate: 1.1,
  StartDate: moment().add(1, 'y'),
};

conn.login('username', 'password', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  conn.sobject('DatedConversionRate').create(create, (err, ret) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(ret);
  });
});
```

When I try and create the object this error is being thrown.

```
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: You cannot edit an unused currency
```

I had looked up what was in the `DatedConversionRate.IsoCode` picklist and I found this record.

```
[
  { 
    active: true,
    defaultValue: false,
    label: 'AED - UAE Dirham',
    validFor: null,
    value: 'AED',
  },
  ...
]
```

So I would have thought that setting `'AED'` as a `IsoCode` would have worked.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DatedConversionRate` Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_datedconversionrate.htm) does not currently support `create`.

The only allowed operations are

- `delete()`
- `describeSObjects()`
- `getDeleted()`
- `getUpdated()`
- `query()`
- `retrieve()`
- `update()`